# Java program show Irrelevant output

Tags: java, math, println

I was doing simple java programming.But I couldn't find why my code doesn't show exect output.It should print the sqrt of given number but the output is 0.

```
import java.lang.*;
class Calculator{
    double i;
    double x=Math.sqrt(i);
    
}
public class MultipleObject {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Calculator a=new Calculator();
        a.i = 16;
        System.out.println(a.x);

    }

}
```

Comment: I think you should check out some basic Java tutorials.

Comment: It's simple: you don't change value of `x` when you call `a.i=16;`  `x` is set to `sqrt(0)` when you create an instance of Calculator.

Answer (score 2):

your are not setting x (Math.sqrt(i)) in the right place

```
import java.lang.*;
class Calculator{
    double i;
//  double x=Math.sqrt(i); // won't work here
    double x;
    
}
public class MultipleObject {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Calculator a=new Calculator();
        a.i = 16;
      // you could do it here
        a.x = Math.sqrt(a.i);
        System.out.println(a.x);

    }

}
```

or what you could do is rather than making it a variable, make it a method

```
  public double getX() {
    return Math.sqrt(this.i);
  }
```

Comment: Why `double x=Math.sqrt(i);` won't work at instance field level? it will.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri it will not, as i as not been initialized yet.

Comment: instance fields are always initialized :)

Comment: @ControlAltDel that's another point, but it will crash at run-time. What I meant, is that there's nothing semantically wrong. `i` can be initialized via constructor, though, as it's not statically bound and constructor will execute before the `Math.sqrt` call.

Comment: @AlexRudenko If you mean initialized to null or 0, then yes. But this isn't helping the conversation with the given code

Comment: @ControlAltDel haha, I was wrong, it doesn't even crash. :))

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri _constructor will execute before_ is not quite true -- if there was constructor initializing _only i_ (e.g. with 16), it would not help to set `x = Math.sqrt(i);` to 4.

Comment: Yeah, agree. Actually was just recalling initialization order.. and it's not clearly given in JLS. But yea.. constructor will execute after static block, static fields, and instance block and instance fields initialized bound statically.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is evaluated when you create an instance of `Calculator`, and at this moment it is `0.0`.

You should pass `i` via constructor, and evaluate `x` in either constructor or method.

```
class Calculator {
   public final double x; 
   Calculator(double i) {
      this.x = Math.sqrt(i);
   }
}
> new Calculator(100).x
$1 ==> 10.0
```